# Convert a datetime string with timezone spelled out in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datetime string coming in with the timezone spelled out rather than given as a number.
For example `2021-3-12 12:00:00 America/Chicago`
All the documentation for ISO formatting doesn't really give a guide on how to convert that. Apart from string splitting, is there a way to convert this datetime format?